# Electric counterpart of gravitational attraction in GR

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

A component of the calculation of an ion’s loss of energy in condensed material is given by the so called Bethe formula.

In the classical derivation of the formula, one lets an ion pass an initially free electron and receives an energy value, which is later modified by considering the mean ionization potential of the traversed medium.
The passage is about inverse square attraction just like gravitation and should therefore be similar to the case of a fast particle passing the Sun giving a Newtonian value for deflection as obtained by Soldner 1801 and a higher value given by Einstein 1915.

I am therefore thinking about parallels to Eddington’s experiment regarding deflection of light and I have two questions:

Is it not the case that the deflection is the result of the Sun’s gravity and therefore a result from the general rather than the special theory of relativity?

And – does the general theory have a counterpart for charge attraction so that special relativity is not sufficient for the treatment of the electrons corresponding deflection by an ion (after a moving ion has been subject to a Lorentz transformation)?

Comment: I will note that, for classical particles, the Rutherford formula applies equally well to any inverse square potential (with suitable modifications to the constants out front).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no sensible influence of gravity in the scattering of free electrons on ions simply due to the fact that the gravity is too weak to generate a sensible effect. To this purpose let's just compare the gravitational effect of an ion whose mass I assume to 50u (50 atomic units) with that of the sun. This ratio $R$ is ($1u = 1.66\cdot 10^{-27}$kg) considering also the different distances of the interacting particles/bodies ($r_{sun}$ is the radius of the sun, and $a_0$ the Bohr's radius )

$$R = \frac{m_{sun}}{m_{ion}}\cdot \frac{a_0^2}{r^2_{sun}} = \frac{2\cdot 10^{30}\text{kg}}{50u}\left(\frac{5.3\cdot 10^{-11}}{7\cdot 10^8}\right)^2 = \frac{2\cdot 10^{30}\text{kg}}{ 50\cdot   1.66\cdot 10^{-27}\text{kg}}\cdot 0.57 \cdot 10^{-38} = 1.4\cdot 10^{17}$$

Therefore the gravitational attraction of the sun is $10^{17}$ times stronger than that of ion to any particle, in particular electrons in the given circumstances. Therefore we can conclude that gravity won't have any sensible effect non-relativistically or relativistically on the electrons traversing matter.
Even if this estimation were wrong by one or two orders of magnitude, the ratio $R$ would be still larger than $10^{15}$ surely enough to assure that the effect of gravity between an electron and an ion plays no role whatsoever in the Bethe-Bloch description.

Comment: Thank you. I was thing in terms of the special theory of relativity – since the electron may have near-light velocity. I take it that this is a general relativity issue related to gravity only.

Comment: My post was about giving an idea of the tinyness of the effect. If you want a description in GR, high velocities can be taken into account, but compared to the description by a gravitational forces, effects of high velocities are of second order, so there are even smaller than $10^{-17}$, so  one can forget it. For Mercury cannot be neglected, its perihelion shift is 43''/century. That's already extremely small. How would one ever find this in electron ion scattering? In physics as an experimental science it is only useful to reflect on effects that has at least a chance to be measured.